# Stack Overflow and Recursion - How to prevent function from returning to original function when its done?

Tags: php, function, recursion, stack-overflow

For Example if i have my code like this (php):

```php
<?php
  somefunc(1);

  function somefunc($a) {
    for($i=1;$i<11;$i++) {
      if ($i==5&&$a) {
        $a--;
        somefunc($a);
      }
      echo "$i <br>";
    }
  }
?>
```

and the output was

1
2
3
4
**1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10**
*5
6
7
8
9
10*

I want output as

1
2
3
4
**1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10**

(the italic part removed)

i dont want it to return to the main function. can something be done about this ?

Comment: Sorry, cannot reproduce [problems with recursion on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241042/stack-overflow-and-recursion-how-to-prevent-function-from-returning-to-origina). (Sorry, couldn't resist. ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return from the function.

```
<?php
somefunc(1);

function somefunc($a) {
  for($i=1;$i<11;$i++) {
    if ($i==5&&$a) {
      $a--;
      return somefunc($a);
    }
    echo "$i <br>";
  }
}
?>
```